# Anbox Cloud - error on control channel: User-Initiated Abort

Tags: cloud, canonical, anbox

After starting a new session of the app and when I try to interact with the app in the dashboard then I get

```
error on control channel: User-Initiated Abort, reason=Close called
```

[image: Screenshot]